# Horizontal scroll bar not showing. What might cause this?

Tags: css

Here's what I have: 1000px `width` div's inside a 100% `width` container with a background image repeating horizontally.

Live: http://www.baskra.com/scroll

When I resize the browser window (anything less than 1000px should generate a horizontal scroll bar, right?), the scroll bar doesn't come up, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

What should I do to make the scrolling bar appear? (Nevermind the slideshow, I'm still working on it.)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vBjeg (Not every image is working, but I believe the most important here is the CSS.)

I appreciate all your thoughts!

Comment: You have a not so simple layout. There is surely a JS that resize the images and anyway, you have container set to 100% of the window, and obviously they scale with it.

Comment: Checked for conflicting overflow rules?

Comment: What about the inside div's with 1000px width? Are they ignored by the outside 100% width container? Is there a way to generate a scroll bar whenever viewport size is < 1000px?

Comment: j08691, how should I do that? I'm not very familiar with overflow yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from `.row`

Comment: Josh, it works like a charm, but what happened to my "Contato" section? http://www.baskra.com/scroll

Comment: Looks like you need a clearfix because of floating elements inside of the `.row`. Check out Nicolas Gallagher's <a href="http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/">micro clearfix</a>

Comment: Adding `overflow:hidden` to `.o-contato` solved the problem. Thank you very much.